# Passing data down to child on event triggered in parent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm rank new to React thus the question.

I have a parent component that has a `button`. This is my code,

```
class MyPage extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { messages: []};
    this.onRefreshClick = this.onRefreshClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {

   ......
  }

  onRefreshClick(){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Refresh clicked !!!");
    fetchMessages(fetch_url + "/" + this.state.user.id).then((res) => {
      this.setState({messages: res});
      console.log(this.state.messages);

    });//end of outer promise
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="col-md-2 left-pane">
          <div className="col-md-2 header-left-block">
            <button className="btn refresh-btn" onClick={this.onRefreshClick} type="submit">Refresh</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-8 middle-pane">
          <ReceivedImages />
        </div>

      </div>

    );
  }

}
```

The messages object is getting populated by the method onRefreshClick when the Refresh button is clicked on the parent.

I want to pass this data to the child component, `<ReceivedImages />` as props and load them when the button is clicked on the parent. How do I do this.
It is easy to simulate this behavior if the refresh button was inside the `<ReceivedImages />` component by using a call back, but how do I do it in this case?

Comment: Pass the messages state as a prop?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply **pass the parent's state down to the children as props**. When the parent's state is updated, the `render()` function will be executed and the children's props will be updated automatically, triggering a re-render of them in turn.

```
<ReceivedImages messages={this.state.messages} />
```

They will be available in the the child component as `this.props.messages`.